# Stable baselines3 creates SB3-{date} folders

Tags: stable-baselines

I am currently using Stable baselines3 A2C. Somehow model.learn() keeps making folders with name of SB3-{current date and time} for each episode. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that model.learn() runs setup_learn() function and this asserts logger to create SB3-{date} folders. Just turning off the line mkdir in configure function will fix the problem.